# Send a command a lan computer with batch file

Tags: batch-file, networking, batch-processing, lan

I wanna run a batch file on a lan computer.
Its like to be shutdown command.

```
shutdown /s /m \\computer1 /t 0
```

but I dont want to shutdown computer, I just want to run a batch file, Is it possible ?
and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run a batch file on a remote computer.

From the link:

> Utilities like Telnet and remote control programs like Symantec's PC
>   Anywhere let you execute programs on remote systems, but they can be a
>   pain to set up and require that you install client software on the
>   remote systems that you wish to access. PsExec is a light-weight
>   telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems,
>   complete with full interactivity for console applications, without
>   having to manually install client software. PsExec's most powerful
>   uses include launching interactive command-prompts on remote systems
>   and remote-enabling tools like IpConfig that otherwise do not have the
>   ability to show information about remote systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic /node:computername process call create "c:\\file.bat"
```

Is how to do it.